# How can I get Safari to print images at their specified size?

Tags: css, image, svg, printing, safari

My website dynamically creates html with inline SVG, which the user is supposed to print out at 100% scale. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari the dimensions of the printed image are way off.

I have no idea why this is happening. The dimensions of svg are defined in mm, e.g.:
`<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='62mm' height='192mm' viewBox='0 0 62 192' preserveAspectRatio='none'>`

I expected it to print true to the specified size. On screen, the graphics are displayed with identical dimensions by all three browsers.

I tried printing a JPG in Safari as well and the print wasn't true to size either.

I applied a crude fix (pre-scaling the SVG for Safari users), but as the scaling Safari applies when printing is dependent on the image width, the scaling feature on my user interface is not working as intended.

I also tried formatting the page for printing with CSS, but no luck so far. Apparently I haven't found the correct setting to override yet.

Edit:
These are my current CSS settings:

```
<style>
            @media print {
        html, body, .container, svg {
            width: 62mm !important;
            height: 192mm !important;
            margin: 0mm !important;
            padding: 0mm!important;
        }}
        @page {
            @page {
            size: 6.2cm 19.2cm !important; 
            margin: 0mm !important;
            padding: 0mm !important;
            </style>
```

I saved as PDF from the print dialog and opened the file in illustrator. Apparently two elements are drawn which are not controlled by the style:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAJzi.jpg)

Does anyone know what they are?

Comment: you can check whether it's a known bug [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/) and if not, report it.

Comment: I can't find this bug on bugzilla, but I'm not sure if it's an acutal bug or something I can control with CSS.